# Finding installed software

Tags: xubuntu

I downloaded a weather app for Xubuntu 18.04. Went to task bar clicked on all and accessories, but it does not show weather indicator. How do I find it?
Thanks

Comment: what exactly was the name of the package? `sudo systemctl restart gdm` might force it into existence. Otherwise you probably want to right click your taskbar and click "add widget" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome. In the XFCE "Menu," you can search for the name. Does it show? In the "Software" application, you can look under the "Installed" tab, and if you find it, "Launch" from there.

How did you install it anyway? Command line in a terminal? Synaptic? Software manager?

Comment: Please ask your questions in the form of a comment, rather than including questions in the answer. Or consider mentioning what the user should do under the circumstances of installing from command line, or the terminal, or from Software Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the external panel plugin "Weather" listed on this page?  https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/start
If so, get it to show on panel,
Open xfce4-settings-manager and select the "Panel" button
Go to the items tab under the panel configuration window
Click the "+" button on the right side of the window
Select the desired plugin to add to the panel from the list of plugins

Answer (score 0):

You can also install Gnome-weather which is not a panel application like the XFCE4-weather-application, but will show in menu, and can be added to the panel as a launcher. From what I can see, installing the latest Gnome-weather (Xubuntu uses quite a few Gnome components anyway) will also update libgweather-common and other dependencies. You can then use either the panel plugin or the application.